# Taylor series remainder term to yield $\ln4$ with error terms less than $2^{-10}$

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I need to derive the taylor series for $\ln(1+x)$ about $1$ then create an inequality that gives the number of terms that must be taken to yield $\ln4$ with error terms less that $2^{-10}$. I got the taylor series to be $$f(x) = ln(2) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}{n \cdot 2^n}$$ I was wondering if someone could help me with the the error term, I think the answer is suppose to be $n > 2^{10}-1$ but I cant seem to figure out how to get there. thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the Taylor series should be about $x=1$?

Comment: @trancelocation yes it was about 1 in this question

Comment: You better use $\ln(4)=2\ln(2)=-2\ln(1-\frac12)$ or $\ln(4)=2(\ln(1+\frac13)-\ln(1-\frac13))$ as the start of your computation. In your formula so far, if you assume the value $\ln2$ known as a constant as in the first term, there is no need to approximate it with the second term. By the way, what exactly is $f(x)$?

Comment: Looking at your suggested answer, the series in question is rather
$\ln(1+x)$ evaluated at $x=1$:
$$\ln 4 = 2\ln(1+1)=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac 1k$$
This is an alternating series and so you have

$$\left|\ln 4 - 2\sum_{k=1}^{\color{blue}{n}}(-1)^{n+1}\frac 1k\right|\leq\frac 2{\color{blue}{n+1}}\stackrel{!}{<}2^{-10}\Rightarrow \boxed{n>2^{11}-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

The remainder term for the partial sum of the first $n$ terms of
$$
\ln(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^k}{k},
$$
apart from the use of advanced Taylor remainder formulas, can be bounded by a geometric series as
$$
\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^k}{k}\right|\le\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1}\frac1{1-|x|}
$$

- This obviously does not work for $x=1$.
- Using the formula $\ln4 = -2\ln(1-\frac12)$ with $x=-\frac12$ would require
  $$
  \frac{2^{1-n}}{n+1}\le 2^{-10}\iff 2^{11}\le(n+1)2^n
  $$
  which is surely the case for $n=11$, but remains true down to $n=8$.
- Using the formula $\ln4=2\bigl(\ln( 1+\frac13)-\ln(1-\frac13)\bigr)$ with $x=\pm\frac13$ naively would require half the error for each series, thus
  $$
  \frac{3^{-n}}{2(n+1)}\le 2^{-11}\iff 2^{10}=2·8^{3}\le(n+1)9^{n/2}
  $$
  which is surely given for $n=6$, but also works for $n=5$. Note that both series have the same terms up to the sign.
- In fact, this last formula has cancelling terms, so the series difference can be written as
  $$
  \ln 4=2\ln2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac4{(2k+1)3^{2k+1}}
  $$
  so that the remainder for the partial sum of the first $n$ terms has the bound
  $$
  \left|\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac4{(2k+1)3^{2k+1}}\right|
  \le\frac4{(2n+1)3^{2n+1}}\frac98=\frac1{2(2n+1)3^{2n-1}}
  $$
  So for the demanded accuracy
  $$
  \frac1{2(2n+1)3^{2n-1}}\le 2^{-10}\iff 3·8^3\le (2n+1)9^{n}
  $$
  which is satisfied for $n=3$.
  $$
  \ln 4\approx\frac43\left(1+\frac1{3·9}+\frac1{5·9^2}\right)=\frac43·\frac{421}{405}=1.386008....
  $$
  compared to $\ln4=1.386294...$